# Adicionar dados em banco de dados através de um link

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, link, inserir

Dei uma rápida pesquisada mas não achei, por isso estou postando aqui. Bom, é o seguinte, quero que quando a pessoa clique em um *link* (no caso `<a href=.......>inserir</a>`) execute o seguinte código SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`) VALUES
('', 'private', '', '', 'Novo modelo de quarto', '1', 'locked', '0', '100', 'model_recep2', 'hh_room_nlobby2', '538', '', '12', '0', '', '', '0.0', '407', '0.0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '-2', '-2', '0');
```

Pelo que vi na Internet deveria ser por `js`, cheguei a criar uma página com a *hash* `$inserirroom` e este SQL acima, mas não sei como fazer isso para que ao clicar no *link* seja executado tal código. Obrigado!

Comment: Simplesmente aponte o href do seu link para o php que faz esse insert. Ou tem algo que eu não entendi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, uma é como o [nosso colega colocou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33228/adicionar-dados-em-banco-de-dados-atrav%c3%a9s-de-um-link#comment63519_33228):
simplesmente aponte o `href` do seu link para o PHP que faz esse *insert*.

Outra forma é executar de forma assíncrona usando AJAX do JavaScript.

Você consegue fazer isso facilmente utilizar o método `.get` ou [`.post` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
fucntion incluir(){
    $.post( "ajax/incluir.php", function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Esse parâmetro data é o retorno do arquivo `.php`, pode ser um `echo 'salvo com sucesso';`.

Lembre-se de chamar esse método `incluir` do JavaScript no evento (pode ser `onclick`) do teu elemento (no seu caso um link) mas poderia ser um botão também.